# How do I access the original data from object in python. Here I've used group by to group data

Tags: django, python-3.x, object, django-rest-framework, python-itertools

I am trying to group data based on the following data fields I have, and when I am not able to access the original data in the fields

Printing the filtered_data is giving something like "object at 0x10dd1abf0>", so I need to access the original human-readable value in the objects.

```
    data_objects = ['*', '*', '*', ......] // This is list of data items
    filterd_data_objects = groupby(
        data_objects, lambda data: (data.x, data.y, data.z) and data.p
    )
    print(filtered_data_objects)
    // This is giving <itertools.groupby object at 0x1066ceb30>, Need to access the original content in the data objects.
    for filterd_data_object, _ in filterd_data_objects:
        x = data_object[0] // this is not working I've tried this to access the original data
        y = data_object[1]
        z = data_object[2]
        p = data_object[3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the ***data_object***  by list like

```
list(data_object)
```

You can refer to this example

```
from itertools import groupby
data_objects  = [{"a": 1}, {"a": 1}, {"a": 2}]

for dobject, x in groupby( data_objects, lambda data : data["a"]):
    print(dobject,list(x))
```